# ssh/login to a buildserver on the network and logout

Tags: python, ssh, build, server, remote-server

I am trying to ssh into a buildserver on the network and run some commands and logout of the server,i have looked at other posts
and written the following code but its not working?can anyone suggest what is wrong or is there a better way to accomplish this?thanks in advance

```
import os
import sys
import pexpect
#os.system(ssh username@buildservername)
child = pexpect.spawn('ssh username@buildservername', logfile=sys.stdout)
#child.expect('Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?')
#child.sendline('yes')
#child.expect('password:')
child.sendline('password')
cmd = 'hostname'
os.system(cmd)
os.chdir('//local/mnt/workspace')
os.mkdir('newdir')
os.getcwd()
```

Comment: What do you mean by " not working " ? Do you get any errors with this code ?

Comment: ``os.system()`` is going to run ``cmd`` on the localhost -- Not the target host. -- Pretty much any ``os.*`` call is goig to run locally not on the remote server.

Comment: @FelixYadomi - meaning am not able to ssh to the buildserver on the network,hostname prints as the server where this script is being run..

Comment: @JamesMills - basically if ssh to remote server is successful,it should create the  directory as in `os.mkdir('newdir')` but it doesnt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look a the [Paramiko](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/1.15/index.html) library, especialy the [SFTPClient](http://paramiko-docs.readthedocs.org/en/1.15/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient)

It's a native Python SSHv2 protocol library.

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('buildservername', username='yadomi', password='password')

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.chdir('/local/mnt/workspace')
sftp.mkdir('newdir')
```

Comment: ,I get the error..`Server 'buildservername' not found in known_hosts`

Comment: Nice use of ``sftp`` there :) Good one!

Comment: @user3682248 coz you should define `Add Policy`, for example auto add policy `ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())`