# how to run custom commands using sftp or ssh or paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

t
I have the following code which uses ssh and sftp to ssh to a buildserver on the network and run the native mkdir and chdir commands,how do I run any custom commands with some executables i have installed locally on the build server?

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('buildservername', username='yadomi', password='password')

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp.chdir('/local/mnt/workspace/newdir')
commandstring = 'repo init -u git://git.company.com/platform/manifest -b branchname --repo-url=git://git.company.com/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=caf/caf-stable'
si,so,se = ssh.exec_command(commandstring) 
readList = so.readlines()
print readList
print se
```

Error:-

```
<paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 1 (closed) -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x2730310L (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 1 open channel(s))>>>
```

Comment: exact duplicate of [ssh/login to a buildserver on the network and logout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29957312/ssh-login-to-a-buildserver-on-the-network-and-logout)

Comment: As long as `PATH` env variable is correct all you need is `si,so,se = ssh.exec_command(commandstring)`                              
 `readList = so.readlines()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You open an SFTP channel and set its working directory, but you never do anything else with that channel. Perhaps you believe that sets the working directory for a subsequent `exec_command`? It doesn't.

2) You do `print se`, but don't recognize the output. Perhaps you believe that prints the error stream from the invoked command? It doesn't.

Try this:

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.connect('buildservername', username='yadomi', password='password')

commandstring = 'cd /local/mnt/workspace/newdir ; repo init -u git://git.company.com/platform/manifest -b branchname --repo-url=git://git.company.com/tools/repo.git --repo-branch=caf/caf-stable'
si,so,se = ssh.exec_command(commandstring) 
readList = so.readlines()
errList = se.readlines()
print readList
print errList
```

---

The answer to your literal question, "*how do I run any custom commands with some executables i have installed locally on the build server?*", is "by passing the appropriate command line to `ssh.exec_command()`".

Comment: After running the `ssh.exec_command(commandstring)` the python script just hangs,i can see the command is successful as I can see the .repo file in the directory,how to debug why its stuck?

Comment: What changed between "thanks, that works" and "the python script just hangs"? If you have one working script and one non-working script, one way to debug them is to make small incremental changes to one of them until either it starts to work or until the two scripts are identical.

Comment: Alternatively, determine precisely where the Python script is hanging. Add `print` statements liberally to your script. Find the precise line that is never finishing.

Comment: nothing changed,I jumped the gun too early,i saw .repo getting created and thought it worked ,i added print statements and found out that  the script is stuck at `readList = so.readlines()` ,any idea why is that?may be there is no `so and se` ?

Comment: That means that the remote shell has not yet exited for some reason. I do not know why that might be. Try changing your command to "cd /whatever/path/you/need ; ls" and seeing if that returns. If so, then your repo command is doing something odd. If not, then something else is keeping the connection open.